# VSCode Symbol Rename not working with Go

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Whenever I attempt to use "Rename Symbol" in VSCode while editing a Go project, it fails.  Based on the error messages, it looks like it's only using GOROOT, and ignoring everything under GOPATH.

When I first tried using it, it gave me the following error:

> Cannot rename due to errors:
>   /usr/local/go/src/net/interface_bsd.go:12:2: could not import
>   golang_org/x/net/route (cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/route"
>   in any of: /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/route (from $GOROOT).

This package was present under GOPATH.  I copied the entire "golang.org" directory to GOROOT/src, and renamed to "golang_org".  That eliminated that error, but now I'm getting errors regarding my own project's packages "not found".

Everything else in my GO development system and VS Code is working OK... auto reformat on save, errors, Intellisense, etc.

go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/james/Dropbox/Development/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

System & Editor:

```
MacOS 10.10.5
go version go1.7.4 darwin/amd64
VSCode 1.7.2
```

VS Code Extensions:

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go (0.6.51)  
Dash 1.1.2
```

Comment: `golang_org/x` is vendored in the go source. Make sure your GOROOT is complete and at the same version as your go binaries.

Comment: I just uninstalled / reinstalled Go, as per https://golang.org/doc/install#install: 1) deleted /usr/local/go, 2) deleted /etc/paths.d/go, 3) removed /usr/local/go from path.  Then reinstalled using the standard MacOS package from: https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.7.4.darwin-amd64.pkg.  There is no "golang_org" directory anywhere in the /usr/local/go or any subdirs...  I'm not sure how to "make sure GOROOT is complete" other than this?

Comment: Correction to above -  The only "golang_org" directory is at "/usr/local/go/src/vendor/golang_org"... which is not the path the error continues to call out as per my original post.

Comment: That is the correct path where it _should_ resolve the `golang_org/x/net/route` package. Do you have the latest versions of `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename` and `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru` installed?

Comment: That looks to have helped.  Thanks Jim!  Question: when I update Go, is there any expeditious way to also update all the golang.org/x/... contents, other than repeated "go get -u " calls for each package?

Comment: Nope. Those are separate tools with separate upgrade cycles.